# Prevent trailing and leading spaces in VS Code multiline comments

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

When multiline comment is added with Shift+Ctrl+A, trailing space is added at `/*` line, this may cause linter problems:

[image: [multiline comment]

I'm comfortable with `no-trailing-spaces` linter rule regarding comments and would prefer to not change it because of VS Code quirks.

Leading space before `*/` doesn't cause linter problems but I would like to get rid of it because it looks displaced and I don't use intermediate asterisks in multiline comments like:

```
/*
 * multiline
 * comment
 */
```

Can a way spaces are added to multiline comments be changed in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT for v1.42 (setting is "Comments: Insert Space") :

Apparently coming to v1.42 is this setting `editor.insertSpaceAfterComment` which seems to solve your problem in the block comment case.  But if disabled no spaces will be inserted after line `//` comment notation, so `//comment starts immediately` instead of `// comment starts after space`.  This may or may not be acceptable to you.

[image]

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/41747

---

If you have

```
"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": true
```

when you save the file  it will remove that trailing whitespace.  Alternatively, using the command `editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace` will also remove the trailing spaces in the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>.

Modifying the built-in snippets is tricky since they can be overridden upon updates.

You could make a **macro** that deletes the space in one go.  I presume you meant <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>: that is the command for toggling block comments on my vscode.  You said Shift+Ctrl+A in your question which is unbound for me.

Using the extension [multiCommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command): (in your settings.json)

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.blockComment",

  "sequence": [
     "editor.action.blockComment",
     "editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace",
     "cancelSelection",
     "deleteRight"
   ]
},
```

Those last two commands get rid of the leading space before the `*/` as you requested.

In your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+a",
  "command": "-editor.action.blockComment",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+a",
  "command": "multiCommand.blockComment",
},
```

And then invoke with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, toggling off still works too.

[image: Demo of macro running].

[The gif goes a little nuts on the entered keystrokes, it Is only <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Put me on the way, seems now the variable to play with is `editor.comments.InsertSpace` for leading spaces (version VSCode: 1.50.1)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the answer above:

I was having trouble with the `/**/` completion in VS Code.  As soon as the second `*` was typed, VS Code would add a `*/` to the end - extremely annoying, as we have set formatting for comments, and using the god awful:

```
/*
 * Some comment
 */
```

...format is abhorrent to me.

To combat this, navigate to the `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript` folder.  Make a backup of the **javascript-language-configuration.json** file, then edit it. In the `autoClosingPairs` section, change...

```
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        ...
        { "open": "/**", "close": " */", "notIn": ["string"] }
    ],
```

...to...

```
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        ...
        { "open": "/*", "close": "*/", "notIn": ["string"] }
    ],
```

Comment: Just a note that you might have to do this after every update, your changes may be overwritten if the default file got changed.